# it takes 2 clicks to activate jquery function and 1 click afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need help with this code it takes 2 clicks to fire up and 1 click afterwards.
i'm new to this and this is a good place to get some advice.

```
 function setTextGPU(){

$("#GPUs li").click(function() {


document.getElementById('GPU').value = $(this).html();

});

}
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="fieldValue">
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
    <input type="text" name="GPU" id="GPU" class="quote vga_val ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="dropdown" readonly>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id=GPUs aria-labelledby="GPU">
    <?php
    $query=("select name,price from oc_product_description natural join oc_product_to_category natural join oc_product where category_id = 481 and status=1 and quantity>0");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($GPU = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        echo '<li class=dropdown-item onclick=setTextGPU()>' . $GPU['name'].'             Cost : '.round($GPU['price']).'$</li>';
    }
    ?>
   </ul>

    <input name="gpu-qty" class="quote-qty " type="number" value="1" min="1">
</div>
```

Comment: where is this "#GPUs li" selector defined?

Comment: Don't use both inline event listener and jQuery event listener. Use one or the other

Comment: #GPUs is the ul name.

Comment: If it's a `<ul>` name, you are using wrong selector, make it `ul` id and then use `#GPUs`

Comment: my bad it is indeed the ul id =>  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id=GPUs aria-labelledby="GPU">

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong on the click event binding. Never attach the function inline and bind again in javascript at the same time.

Updated code:

```js
$("#GPUs li").click(function() {


  document.getElementById('GPU').value = $(this).html();

});
```

```html
<div class="fieldValue">
  <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
  <input type="text" name="GPU" id="GPU" class="quote vga_val ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="dropdown" readonly>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id=GPUs aria-labelledby="GPU">
    <?php
    $query=("select name,price from oc_product_description natural join oc_product_to_category natural join oc_product where category_id = 481 and status=1 and quantity>0");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($GPU = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        echo '<li class=dropdown-item>' . $GPU['name'].'             Cost : '.round($GPU['price']).'$</li>';
    }
    ?>
  </ul>

  <input name="gpu-qty" class="quote-qty " type="number" value="1" min="1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

still the same now it doesn't input anything.

```js
$("#GPUs li").click(function() {


  document.getElementById('GPU').value = $(this).html();

});
```

```html
<div class="fieldValue">
  <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
  <input type="text" name="GPU" id="GPU" class="quote vga_val ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="dropdown" readonly>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id=GPUs aria-labelledby="GPU">
    <?php
    $query=("select name,price from oc_product_description natural join oc_product_to_category natural join oc_product where category_id = 481 and status=1 and quantity>0");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($GPU = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        echo '<li class=dropdown-item>' . $GPU['name'].'             Cost : '.round($GPU['price']).'$</li>';
    }
    ?>
  </ul>

  <input name="gpu-qty" class="quote-qty " type="number" value="1" min="1">
</div>
```